# Adding data to an existing php file via submission of a form

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
function send($uName, $pWord) {
    $var_str1 = var_export($uName, true);
    $var_str2 = var_export($pWord, true);
    $var = "<?php\n\n\$uName = $var_str1;\n\$pWord = $var_str2;\n\n?>";
    file_put_contents('textBit.php', $var);

}
function checker($uName, $pWord){
    $pwLen = strlen($pWord);
    $uLen = strlen($uName);
    $pwNum = is_numeric($pWord);
    if ($pwLen < 12 && $uLen < 12 && $pwNum == 1) {
        echo "Thanks $uName, your information has been saved.";
        send($uName, $pWord);             
    }
    elseif ($pwLen == 0 && $uLen == 0) {
        echo "Both a password and a username is required";
    }
    elseif ($pwLen > 12) {
        echo "Password too long";
    }
    elseif ($pwLen == 0) {
        echo "Needs password";
    }
    elseif ($uLen > 12) {
        echo "Username too long";
    }
    elseif ($uLen == 0) {
        echo "Needs username";
    }
    elseif ($pwNum == 0) {
        echo "Password needs at least 1 number";
    }
    
}
function confirm() {
    $uName = $_POST["uName"];
    $pWord = $_POST["pWord"];
    echo "Your Name is: ";
    echo $_POST["uName"];
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo "Your Password is: ";
    echo $_POST["pWord"];
    echo "<br>";
    checker($uName, $pWord);
}
confirm();
?>
```

'''

The end goal is for it to send this data to another php file. It does this but also deletes the file last data submitted (Because of it having the same var name). Is there a way i can make it add data to the bottom of the separate php file using a different variable name and not delete the last submission automatically?
Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've only been learning for a day. Oh and this isn't for a business or anything just a personal interest so i wont need to be encrypting anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check if file exists and add third argument `FILE_APPEND` to your `file_put_contents`. Just don't put `?>` at the end of your file

```php
function send($uName, $pWord) {
    $var_str1 = var_export($uName, true);
    $var_str2 = var_export($pWord, true);
    $path = 'textBit.php';
    $var = '';

    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        $var .= "<?php\n\n";
    }
    $var = "\$uName = $var_str1;\n\$pWord = $var_str2;\n\n";

    file_put_contents($path, $var, FILE_APPEND);
}
```